# heroku deployment problems, returns :fatal: No path specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku

I'm a windows user who has been learning the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/ruby-on-rails-tutorial) and I have been following everything perfectly until I try to deploy an app to heroku with:

```
sample_app>git push heroku master
fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax
```

I have looked at similar questions, and all proposed fixes did not work for me. Some additional info that might be useful:

```
sample_app>git remote -v
heroku  [git@heroku.com:oscure-dawn-8059.git] (fetch)
heroku  [git@heroku.com:oscure-dawn-8059.git] (push)
origin  [git@github.com:hassankbrian/sample_app.git] (fetch)
origin  [git@github.com:hassankbrian/sample_app.git] (push)
```

Here are the contents of .git/config:

```
[user]
        name =  Brian   
        email = hassankbrian@gmail.com
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = [git@github.com:hassankbrian/sample_app.git]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "heroku"]
    url = [git@heroku.com:oscure-dawn-8059.git]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[heroku]
    remote = heroku
```

Comment: Heroku sometimes fails to setup a repo/instance correctly. So when ever I run into these issues with heroku I just nuke the current instance and create another one, along with another repo, and then try pushing up to the new repo. I have banged my head against the walls for hours sometimes to only find out its a heorku initialization issue and there is no real other solution but to recreate the instance.

Comment: I actually did that, but it is giving me the same thing over and over again. I don't know what possibly went wrong several times with different apps as well.

Comment: Well shoot... Only thing I can think of is pushing up all your changes to github, then just do a new clone down, and trying to create the heroku app from that new local version and see if that helps. Your local git repo might be out of sorts. I would also keep an eye on https://status.heroku.com/, just in case they are having some type of isssue.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the combination of using the "ssh://" prefix and the relative syntax in the repository name. Seems to be related to gitolite being used. The absense of a slash coupled with the "ssh://" prefix seems to confuse it.

- ssh://git@server:relative - NO
- git@server:relative - YES
- ssh://git@server/relative - MAYBE (gitolite is happy with this)
- ssh://git@server:/relative - MAYBE (gitolite is happy with this)
- ssh://git@server/absolute - YES

Hope this helps.